# In this problem, what am I taking the integral of?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm a little confused by this problem because I have no idea what I should be taking the integral of. I was following a book example when I realised that the book explicitly tells you what to take the integral of.

Problem: Find the surface area of the piece of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ cut off by the planes $z = 0$ and $y = z$ with $y \ge 0$.

I let $x=2\cos(\theta)$ and $y = 2\sin(\theta)$ and $z=z$ where $0 \le  \theta  \le 2\pi$ and $ 0 \le z \le 2\sin(\theta)$.

|R0 x Rz| = 2

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be taking an integral of anything. You're finding the surface area. Find the area of the three surfaces and add them up and voila, you have the answer.

Comment: But the formula for surface integrals is is the double integral of f(r(u,v))|Ru x rv|dA

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the integral of one. Also, theta is from 0 to pi